# There is + the (with nouns like "the floor")

Tags: definite-article, existentials

> Be careful! There is the brick wall behind you.

The wall featured in this situation is the only thing like the ceiling or the floor. There are no other walls, just this one. But the wall wasn't mentioned previously.

Does the sentence have the right to exist, with the definite article?

Comment: You can warn someone about something you think they should already know about  (either from context or general knowledge) or will soon discover, using the definite article.  *Don't forget about about the fire hydrant when backing up. I assume you saw it?* The thing does not have to be mentioned previously.  *I heard you're going to that new restaurant on Main Street. Have fun with the stomach distress afterwards.*

Comment: That is the essential nature of a warning. The very fact that you're using **the** out of the blue underscores the difference in your knowledge and theirs.

Comment: Did the question go over your head? How come you so diligently managed to avoid using the core construction in your examples which is "there is the"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existential *there* normally takes a notional subject (the noun after the copular) with an indefinite article. So an indefinite article should be used in the  sentence since there is no appropriate reason to use the definite one.

However, it's not always wrong to a definite article with *there*. You can use it when it introduces a series of new information elements.

> Existential clauses also sometimes have notional subjects that are definite noun phrases or proper nouns. For example:
>
> - ***First** there was the scandal of Fergie romping with John Bryan, pictured exclusively in the Mirror. (NEWS)*
> - *There is **also** the group of non-benzenoid aromatic compounds. (ACAD)*
>
> As in these examples, the definite noun phrases usually occur when a series of new information elements is introduced, often marked explicitly with a linking adverbial or additive adverb (e.g. *first*, *also*).
>
> <sub>Biber et al, Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English</sub>